# Targeting first letter of each word in h1 using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to wrap the first letter of each word in my heading tags with a span class so that I can style them using CSS. I have tried to use a snippet I've found on here, but I have 2 h1 tags and it is taking the first one and repeating it for the second!

The function is this:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var words = $('h1').text().split(' ');
    var html = '';
    $.each(words, function() {
      html += '<span class="firstLetter">' + this.substring(0, 1) + '</span>' + this.substring(1) + ' ';
      $('h1').html(html);
    });

  });
</script>
```

So I have an h1 in the banner at the top, and another one at the start of the content, but the function is taking the top banner heading and replacing the content heading with it, but the span class is working!

I know you shouldn't have 2 h1s, but I want to target all headings anyway, and its a CMS for a client so I can't guarantee they won't use multiple h1 going forwards, so I am testing it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per OP's request, this will "wrap the first letter of each word".

Since there are two `<h1>` elements (as OP said, very wrong), one should iterate them using `each` too, same way OP did with the `words` array.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('h1').each( function(index, heading) {
    
      const words = $(heading).text().split(' ')
      let html = '';
      
      $.each(words, function() {
        html += '<span class="firstLetter">'+this.substring(0,1)+'</span>'+this.substring(1) + ' ';
      })
      
      $(heading).html(html);
    })
    
});
```

```css
span.firstLetter {
  color: violet;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>

<hr>

<h1>Bacon ipsum dolor amet biltong pork chop bacon</h1>
```

Answer (score 6):

Recursively loop over the text nodes inside the headings and then wrap the words within a `span` and replace the text node with a container span that holds all the wrapped words.

Then style the first letter of these `span`s using the [::first-letter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter) CSS pseudo element.

**NOTE:**

1. **Directly replacing the `innerHTML` of the headings might cause bugs if the headings have elements in them.**

   For ex: In the snippet below, the headings have some elements within them. The first one has an anchor element and the second one has an svg and these are common use cases. But if you directly replace the `innerHTML` of these headings that would eliminate these elements inside them, which is *not* desired. So, it's essential that you only wrap the text nodes within a `span`.
2. `::first-letter` *only* works with block-level elements, so you need to set the `display` property of `span`s to `inline-block`.

```js
const headingEls = document.querySelectorAll("h1");

function wrapWithSpan(node) {
  if (node.nodeName === "#text") {
    const containerSpan = document.createElement("span");
    containerSpan.innerHTML = node.textContent
      .split(" ")
      .map((word) => `<span class="word-span">${word}</span>`)
      .join(" ");
    node.parentNode.replaceChild(containerSpan, node);
  } else {
    Array.from(node.childNodes).forEach(wrapWithSpan);
  }
}

headingEls.forEach(wrapWithSpan);
```

```css
a[href^="#"] {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

a[href^="#"]:hover,
a[href^="#"]:hover *,
a[href^="#"]:focus,
a[href^="#"]:focus * {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

a[href^="#"]:hover::after,
a[href^="#"]:focus::after {
  color: #aaa;
  content: "#";
  margin-left: 0.25rem;
  font-size: 0.75em;
}

h1 .word-span {
  display: inline-block;
}

h1 .word-span::first-letter {
  color: palevioletred;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="heading"><a href="#heading">Heading with link</a></h1>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>

<h1>Heading with SVG <svg height="20" width="20"><circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10" fill="green" /></svg></h1>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
```

If you just want to style the first letter of each heading, you *don't* need JS, you can do it by using only the [::first-letter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter) CSS pseudo element.

```css
a[href^="#"] {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}

a[href^="#"]:hover,
a[href^="#"]:focus {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

a[href^="#"]:hover::after,
a[href^="#"]:focus::after {
  color: #aaa;
  content: "#";
  margin-left: 0.25rem;
  font-size: 0.75em;
}

h1::first-letter {
  color: palevioletred;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="heading"><a href="#heading">Heading with link</a></h1>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>

<h1>Heading with SVG <svg height="20" width="20"><circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10" fill="green" /></svg></h1>
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
  in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
```

Comment: I think OP wants to wrap the first letter of every single word: "I am trying to wrap the first letter of each word in my heading tags"

Comment: Yes its the first letter of each word, not just the first word

Comment: @GrafiCode I've updated my answer to handle that scenario as well, please have a look!

Comment: now it's complete. this should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

```
const h1 = document.getElementsByTagName("H1");
for (const item of h1) item.innerHTML = item.innerText.split(" ").map(word => "<span style='color: red !important;'>" + word[0] + "</span>" + word.slice(1)).join(" ")
```

Assuming that the your `h1` tags have no children. Its easy to modify this to get the correct result though.

Comment: This one only targetted first letter of first word? Anyway, solution is below for anyone else looking!

Comment: "I am trying to wrap the first letter of each word".

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```css
.firstLetter
{
color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<h1>Goodbye World</h1>

<script>
        var h1s = document.getElementsByTagName('h1');
        for(const h1 of h1s)
        {
            let text = h1.innerText.split(' ');
            let html = "";
            for(const word of text)
            {
             html += '<span class="firstLetter">' + word.substring(0, 1) + '</span>' + word.substring(1) + ' ';
            }
            h1.innerHTML = html;
        }
        
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To style *each* first letter of every word in every heading, you can use jQuery's [`.html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html/) (as you're using jQuery in your question). This will loop over each `h1`, and replace the text within it with the returned value. The new value [replaces](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) the first letter of each word (referred to using `$&` in the replacement argument) matched using the [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) `\b\w` (which matches a [word boundary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Assertions#boundary-type_assertions) (`\b`) followed by a character (`\w`)) with the character itself wrapped in `<span>` tags:

```js
$("h1").html(function(i, txt) {
  return txt.replace(/\b\w/g, '<span class="firstLetter">$&</span>');
});
```

```css
.firstLetter {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>This is a heading</h1>
<h1>This is another heading</h1>
```